# How to add text to surfaces of complex 3D models in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, 3d-model

I would like to add small text, less than 10 letters to the surfaces of complex 3D models, such as a person model or a building.

One way is to add the image texture to a material, and then add the material to the model. But by this way I can not control where the text will be placed. For example, if I use the material with a text texture to a cube, all the 6 surfaces will display the text. This is what I don't want it be. I just need the text displayed only once, wherever it is.

What I need is just to add some text on the surface anywhere, even randomly.

Can I realize this by Unity itself without other softwares like Maya, Photoshop?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use unity tag got questions related to Unity game engine. There's unity3d tag for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a text mesh and a text renderer ...

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html

As always with unity there's a tool for that :)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and tell you whether it works for my demands.